# Cloud Scheduler randomness

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-scheduler

I want to run a Cloud Function every day at a random time between 1 pm and 2 pm. I use Cloud Scheduler (cron) to publish a message to PubSub that is triggering the function. I want to make that randomness on the Cloud Scheduler side to avoid calling sleep in the function.
Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Please upvote this feature request: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/142630271

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't do that. You need an intermediary layer. The cheapest is to use [Cloud Workflows](https://cloud.google.com/workflows).

The power of Cloud Workflow is you pay only when you run a step, not on the workflow duration. Therefore you can sleep for a while, you won't pay for the idle CPU that you don't use, thing that happen when you use Cloud Functions or Cloud Run (when you put a SLEEP in your code).

Here the process:

- Create a [step that call a URL](https://cloud.google.com/workflows/docs/reference/stdlib/http/get) that generate a random number. If you haven't a public URL that do that, you can use [this sample](https://cloud.google.com/workflows/docs/samples/workflows-functions-randomgen) with a Cloud Funcions
- Create a following [step that sleeps](https://cloud.google.com/workflows/docs/reference/stdlib/sys/sleep) according to your random result of the previous step
- Call your Cloud Function

And you [call your workflow with Cloud Scheduler](https://cloud.google.com/workflows/docs/schedule-workflow) on a daily basis